Generating the $n^{th}$ unique cartesian product from a set of elements
I'm optimizing some code which calculates collisions between bodies. Bodies have collision shapes, which are stored in lists of integers. The first step is understanding which shapes may collide with others. To do this naively, the code calculates the Cartesian product of the list of all shapes with itself, then iterates over the product, adding unique pairs to another list contact_pairs. This is expressed like so in Python:
for shape_a, shape_b in itertools.product(shapes, shapes):
    if shape_a < shape_b:
        contact_pairs.append((shape_a, shape_b))

That offers good runtime performance, but the number of products is of course very high. For a given number of bodies $b$ with $s$ shapes each, the number of unique products is on the order of $s^2$. Specifically, because bodies do not collide with themselves, it's $\sum_{n=1}^{b}{(b-n) * s^2}$, or $\frac{b(b-1)*s^2}{2}$. That's almost a billion pairs for 2000 bodies at 20 shapes each.
However, these pairs of shapes are only necessary for informing the first phase of the collision detection, wherein an operation like this is performed:
shape_a = contact_pairs[idx, 0]
shape_b = contact_pairs[idx, 1]

The only (relevant) thing this array is used for is finding the relevant indices to act on!
This suggests an optimization: rather than calculating all the pairs, we should generate them at runtime from an integer index and the list of shapes. This is where I'm stuck. I imagine that this answer will have something to do with a certain term of the series. Any pushes in the right direction are very appreciated!
